# How do you run code on closing a Jquery dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I am basically using a jquery dialog to do a "Are you sure you want to change mode without saving changes" dialog, and for this I have two buttons, yes, and no. Yes goes ahead and changes form, whereas no reverts it back to normal "as this is activated by changing select.
What I would wish to do is have it run the no code on clicking the x to quit the dialog, but I cant seem to find out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the close event: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-close

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   close: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Comment: Thankyou this is perfect! I have no idea why I didn't look at the events section of that, I guess I need to RTFM sometimes more :)

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to make it check if a button was pressed or not on close

Answer (score 0):

Use the [beforeClose](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-beforeClose) event and return `false` if you want the dialog to stay open if they choose No.